# Check conditions before proceed an URL

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use SpringFramework and Thymleaf to design a web page.

I have a link in one of my html fiels:

```
<a th:id="_following_list" th:href="@{'/table'(id=${0})}">Followings</a> 
<span style="color:white;" th:text="${following_count}"></span>
```

I want to go to /table?id=0 URL only when some conditions are true, otherwise I want to show an alert. Also, I want to apply some changes on some div in the current page when the function in this URL return successfully.

My idea was using ajax, something like this:

```
$(function () {$("#_follower_list").click(function () {
event.preventDefault();
var $post = $(this);
var toSend = {
    "userId" : 0
}
var currentCredit_followerList = 
parseInt($('#_followerList_credit').text());
if(currentCredit_followerList != 0) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: $($post).attr("href"),
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.status == "success") {
            var newCredit_followerList = currentCredit_followerList - 1;
            $('#_followerList_credit').text(newCredit_followerList);
            window.location.href = "table";
            return false;
        }
        else if (data.status == "error") {//do something
        }
        else if (data.status == "ratelimit") {
            window.location.href = "ratelimit";
        }
    });

}else {
    //Show Alarm!
    $('#_credit_error').fadeIn(1000);
}
})
})
```

the problem is that the link looking for its controller, but I want to send the request by json.

What can I do for this scenario? I want th:id="_following_list" be a link, so I don't want to change it to div or delete th:href

Comment: So you're sending the request via ajax, and then you're handling the response properly by javascript. What exactly stops you from deleting `th:href` (and preventing from triggering controller thanks to it)?

Comment: @Jakub When I delete th:href the mouse doesn't change to hand cursor when mouse hovered the link.

Comment: But is a click handled? For cursor issue you can apply a css rule `a { cursor: pointer; }`. Then your `<a>` would looks good and acts as you'd like to.

Comment: @JakubCh. I have fixed this problem by puting href="#about"  and th:id="${'/table?id=0'}" in <a> tag. Now, the problem is that the script must be in the .html file to work. If I put the function in .js, which I add to .html, the function will not work on click!

Comment: The problem in the last comment solved.The problem was with syntax!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)